# Django does not make migrations of multiple models under app_label?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class User(models.Model):
   ......
   ......
   class Meta:
     app_label = 'app_name'

class Customer(models.Model):
   ......
   ......
   class Meta:
     app_label = 'app_name'
```

Only User model is created but Customer model is not created. I am creating models out of app scope

Comment: Did you add your app names inside INSTALLED_APPS = [..] in your settings.py?

Comment: Yes I add app name under INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Migrations are successfully created but only for first model

Comment: Did you add other models later or it exist  always?

Comment: I added them later but I delete previous migrations and create from scratch but still migrations are created only for first model

Comment: so you ran the migrations then deleted the migrations file? Did you remove the entry from the database as well?

What happens if you run ```python manage.py showmigrations```?

Comment: Yes I delete the database as well and create from scratch